# Android - Detect unified volume devices

Tags: android, volume

I have an app that uses `AudioManager` class to set Ringtone and Notification volume, but unlike my Samsung and LG devices that have separate volume controls for Ringer and Notifications, many of my users have android devices with a unified volume for both Ringer and Notification.

For example, the Motorola Moto Z play with Android 8.0 has unified volume, where a Samsung Galaxy Note 8 with Android 8.0 has separate volume controls.

How do I detect at runtime if a device has unified volume control?

Answer (score 0):

Old Android versions doesn't support multiply audio sources volume you could control. That's why users see only one volume control which change volume level for everything - media, ring etc.

Comment: It's not just based on android version, it's based on manufacturer and model. For example, the Motorola Moto Z Play with Android 8.0 has unified volume, where my Note 8 on Android 8.0 has separate volume controls.